# While loop issue for a beginner programmer

Tags: java, while-loop

please do keep in mind I am a brand new computer programmer and I am very stuck on this program I have to write. I already had asked a question earlier and got some great feedback and it's almost complete. The problem I am having is that in the program I am using a for a loop but technically I am only supposed to use while loops and am having major compile issues when trying to revert it to a while loop. Here is an example of the code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Harrison5a1 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

         int integerx;
        System.out.print("Enter an even integer x: ");
        integerx = input.nextInt();

        while (integerx % 2 != 0) 
        {
            System.out.print("Try again, enter an even integer x: ");
            integerx = input.nextInt();
        }

        for (int x = 4; x <= integerx; x += 4) 
        {
            System.out.println("4 is a multiple of " + x);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are your "major compile issues"?

Comment: It running fine no compilation issues.

Comment: Your question is way too specific to be any kind of useful to the StackOverflow community. Nonetheless, if you want to transform your for loop into a while :
int x = 4;
while(x <= integerx) {
    System.out.println("4 is a multiple of " + x);
    x += 4;
}

Comment: so you want to transform your last (for loop) to a (while loop)

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafiz that is correct

Comment: @JeremyGrand experimenting now with your example thank you

Comment: what should the program do, from what i see it will ask for an even then if it is not even it will loop till it get an even then what should the last loop do

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafiz The last loop will then take that even number and get the multiples 4 from it

Comment: you mean the lowest common multiple of both that input even and the number 4

Comment: or to multiply that number by 4 and print it

Comment: or keep multiply that number by 4 and printing it 4 times

Comment: Enter an even integer x: 12
4 is a multiple of 8
4 is a multiple of 12

Comment: example of some output, but my issue now is its not showing that 4 is a multiple of 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if all you want is to transform the last loop (for loop) into a while then all you need is

```
int x = 4; // the for loop initialization 
while(x <= integerx){ // for loop evaluation (done every iteration)
    System.out.println("4 is a multiple of " + x); // whatever you want
    x += 4; // for loop update 
}
```

This does the exact same thing as a foor loop, and every for loop can be turned into a while loop and vice-versa, it can be more readable or not but that is up to the programmer.

**EDIT** I have tested it on [Online Compiler Java](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php) and it works as you intend (if i perceived your requirements in the comments rightfully).

Comment: exactly how i had it coded and it works just fine, but I am having an issue with the output giving me the wrong answer

Comment: Enter an even integer x: 12
    4 is a multiple of 8
    4 is a multiple of 12
   4 is a multiple of 16

Comment: see I am getting 4 is a multiple of 16 also it won't display 4 is a multiple of 4 and I don't understand why

Comment: what is the expected answear and the input, we need to see your input, output and expected output please.

Comment: Expected input is an even number from the user then from there the program must calculate the multiples of it by 4 so an example would be the user inputted 12 as is integer. the expected output thus would be                 4 is a multiple of 4                                                                                                                 4 is a multiple of 8                                                                                                       4 is a multiple of 12

Comment: @Edu G it now prints only 4 is a multiple of 12 three times

Comment: @EduG after tweaking with it I fixed the problem thank you very much for your answer!!

Comment: sorry, there was a typo, just replace the for loop with my code exactly and it should work, i have tested it. @CodyHarrison

Answer (score 0):

Your original requirements, posted 2 days ago where you got the code you're now trying to fix, are as follows:
Your program will do the following:

1. Prompt the user to enter an even integer x
2. Continue to prompt the user for x until the user enters an even integer
3. The program will then print all the even integers between 2 and x that are multiples of four.

None of the code above will accomplish step 3. I suggest you read step 3 very closely, figure out how you would accomplish it without code (on a piece of paper, for example) and only then try to code it. You also need to read your text book and actually understand what these loops are doing instead of asking people to write them for you. You're in school, presumably, to learn how to code. Come back and ask a reasonable question after you have actually tried to do it and looked at your text book and some other examples.